# How to store Hibernate Envers audit tables into a different schema?

Tags: hibernate

How to configure Hibernate Envers to store audit tables into a different schema?

[jpa](/questions/tagged/jpa)[hibernate-envers](/questions/tagged/hibernate-envers)

Answer (score 5):

According to the [hibernate user guide - envers configuration documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#envers-configuration) this should be possible by setting the configuration

```
org.hibernate.envers.default_schema
```

defaulting to

> null (same schema as table being audited)
>
> The default schema name that should be used for audit tables. Can be
>   overridden using the @AuditTable( schema="…​" ) annotation. If not
>   present, the schema will be the same as the schema of the table being
>   audited.

Answer (score 3):

When using JPA the configuration key must be prefixed with `spring.jpa.properties`:

```
spring.jpa.properties.org.hibernate.envers.default_schema=customaudit
```